# are there any fresh ideas for a recursive function printing square pattern?

Tags: java, recursion

i have a question where i need to do a recursive function getting int and doing star pattern of a square like if i insert 4 into the function it will give me:

```
****
****
****
****
```

so i made this recursion and i want to shrink my idea into one function what can you suggest to improve my design, thanks.

```
static int count = 0;
public static void rect(int num){
    if(count<=0)
        return;
    if(count !=0 && num>0){
        for(int i =0; i<num;i++){
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println();
        count--;
        rect(num);
    }
}
public static void SetCount(int num){
    count = num;
    rect(num);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 6;
    SetCount(i);
}
```

Comment: Small sidenote, method names should always start lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One argument, the size of the square.  No external variables:

```
class Homework {

    public static void square(int side) {
        if (side > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < side; i++) {
                square(-side);
            }
        } else if (side < 0) {
            System.out.print('*');
            square(side + 1);
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        square(5);
    }
}
```

Your solution, and others offered so far, are all recursive on the rows of the square and iterative on the columns.  This solution inverts that -- it's recursive on the columns and iterative on the rows.

**OUTPUT**

```
> java Homework
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can eliminate the `SetCount` method and the second `if` check, something like this would work as well :

```
static int count = 0;

public static void rect(int num) {
    if (count <= 0)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print('*');
    }
    System.out.println();
    count--;
    rect(num);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    count = 4;
    rect(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Check{

 static void rect(int num,int count){
    if(count<=0)
        return;
    if(count !=0 && num>0){
        for(int i =0; i<num;i++){
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println();
        count--;
        rect(num,count);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 6;
    rect(i,i);
}
}
```

Instead of using a class variable count and setting it again and again. Use two paramters for the recursive function. "num" to print stars num times in a single row and "count" to keep track of number of rows.